# Plain java servlet in Grails file upload empty FileItem list

Tags: java, grails, servlets

I came across such problem

I have `HttpServlet` implemented in Java with apache `FileUpload` lib.

When I test this code as simple Java web project and deploy it in Tomcat it works.
But when I deploy this as servlet in Grails project `List<FileItem> items` is always empty.

I am pretty sure that is because something in Grails is consuming request body before I do it in `Servlet`, but I do not know how to force Grails not to consume request before me.

I need to add plain Java servlets to grails project as I need to integrate some already written Java code with Grails.

Here is servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(
                new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                System.out.println(fieldname + "=" + fieldvalue);
            } else {
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                String value = IOUtils.toString(filecontent);
                System.out.println(fieldname + "=" + value);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }
}
```

It just reads request body and prints to sysout.

Now I have form:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <form action="http://localhost:8080/Tst/photoServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="fieldId" value="field_photo"/>
     <input type="file" name="Afile" />
     <input type="submit" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have also added such mapping to `web.xml` in Grails:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>photoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tst.PhotoUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>photoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/photoUpload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```